# Preserving independence after a non-linear ransformation

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $W$ and $X$ are positive valued continuous random variables. Is it possible to find a non-linear function $f$, such that

Independence between $W$ and $X+\frac{X}{W}$ implies independence between  $W$ and $X+f\left(\frac{X}{W}\right)$?

I am guessing it is not possible. Trying to find a counter example, to show if the independence to be hold then $f$ must be a linear function.

Comment: If two random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent, then for any measurable function $f$ and $g$, $f(\xi)$ and $g(\eta)$ are independent.

Comment: One independence yields $X|W\sim \frac W {1+W}D$ for $D=(X|W=w_1)(1+w_1^{-1})$ and the other independence yields $E(g(X+f(X/W)|W))$ is constant. Differentiate with respect to $W$ to get $f'=1$.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks for the hint. Could you please explain a little bit: How the two independence yields the above two quantities? Or please post it as a answer to the question.

Comment: @A.S. I can understand upto: $E(X+f(X/ W)/ W)$ is a constant. But then missing differentiating what? The quantity with in the Expectation? Then how $X>0$ implies $f'=1$.

Comment: Differentiate the conditional expectation that is a constant - hence its derivative is zero.

Comment: @A.S. Then how $f'=1$? I am possible missing something.

Comment: What do you get after you differentiate?

Comment: @A.S. Since the expectation is constant (not involve W), the derivative will 0 (not 1).

Comment: It's a *conditional* expectation - so it depends on W in general - and you know how X given W depends on W.

Comment: @A.S. Even if it depends on $W$ in general, how  $f'=1$? how you are getting the explicit expression for $X/W$?

Comment: $X|W\sim \frac {W}{1+W}D$,$\frac X W|W\sim \frac 1 {1+W}D$, $(Eg(X+f(\frac X W)|W))'=E(g'(\text{stuff})D\frac 1 {(1+W)^2}(1-f'(\frac D {1+W})))=0$ for *any* bounded differentiable $g$ hence $f'=1$.

Comment: @A.S. Now its clear to me. Do you actually need $g$ function? I mean $g(x)=x$ is our case.

Comment: You need that flexibility, since for $g(x)=x$ you could potentially pick a non-linear $f$ that makes the expectation zero, but you can't pick such an $f$ that makes an expectation zero for all suitable $g$'s.

Comment: @A.S. I get it.. Could you please post this as your answer to the question, so that I can accept it.  Thank you very much.